# Custom Woff Fonts "Failed to load resource" 404 Error

Tags: apache, fonts, joomla, webfonts, woff

This is my first post on here so I apologize if something isn't quite right in my post.

I'm using Joomla! 3.10.4 and I am trying to implement a custom font into our site.

However, I'm getting a weird phenomenon that is occurring.

The font seems to work great on all of my other pages. Then when I access a "child" menu item, the custom font is then replaced with some other font that isn't our custom one.

When I take a look at the console within Safari, I see the following:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (KoernerVisions-Regular.woff2, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (koernercreations-medium.woff2, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (koernercreations-regular.woff2, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (koernercreations-medium.woff, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (koernercreations-regular.woff, line 0)
```

Everything seems to be in the correct places and for what it's worth, I'm using Apache.

Any help with this would be supremely appreciate as I'm pulling my hair out at the moment trying to figure this out.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you are a Joomla user or developer, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.